# Connect to Windows shared folder via GUI application?

Tags: smb, shared-folders

I have a Windows machine in my local network and want to access files on it. I've made some locations on this computer shared. When I'm using `smbclient` (console application) or `mount` utility with CIFS option from my other machine with Debian 9 it works fine:

```
$ smbclient -U UserName \\\\ip-address\\SharedFolder ""
$ sudo mount //ip-address/SharedFolder /mnt -t cifs -o username=UserName,sec=ntlm
```

However I can't get to shared folder via GUI applications using `smb://` syntax, nor in GTK-based, nor in KDE-based. I tried Krusader, Konqueror and Nautilus (they use different dialogs). They all open a dialog that requires to enter the password and don't proceed when I leave it blank despite the fact I can connect using console tools without entering a password.

Is there a bug in GUI apps handling empty passwords?

The message in case of GTK apps (like Nautilus or PCManFM) is:

> Password required for share

For Krusader and Konqueror it's:

> please enter authentication information

The only related thing I found is a [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=849525) about `gvfs-mount`, but at least KDE apps don't use `gvfs` as I presume.

Comment: the problem might be in the mount point ownership, the GUI aplication may be accessed as user, and where you are mounting the folder, may be owned by `root`. can you `ls -lah` the folder where you are mounting your wondows share? (that's the folder your GUI apps should use)

Comment: I choose mountpoint myself only when using mount -t cifs. smbclient does not mount anything.
As far as I know KDE apps don't really mount network folders on real system path. It's just an interface. gvfs mirrors shared folders to directories inside /run/user/1000/gvfs/ and I can do it without problem when accessing computer via ssh.